# Partial Ordering on Subsets and Maximal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $M < G$ is called a maximal subgroup if the only subgroups containing $M$ are $M$ and $G$. Prove that if $H$ is a proper subgroup of the finite group $G$, then there is a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $H$.

Let $S = \{K \in \mathcal{P}(G) ~|~ H \subseteq K \subset G \}$. Since  the power set $\mathcal{P}(G)$, the subset $S$ will also be finite. If $S$ is empty, then $H$ will be the maximal subgroup (MSG) of $G$ containing $H$. If not, then $\max(S)$ exists, and either it is a subset without group structure, in which $H$ is the MSG of $G$, or it is subgroup. In either case, we have found a MSG of $G$ containing $H$

Does this sound right? I know I am implicitly relying on certain ideas about partially ordered sets and maximal elements, so I am hoping someone could help by verifying I am using the right ideas and language.

**EDIT:** Made a Mistake: $S$ will never be empty given how I defined it, but that shouldn't change the solution too drastically.

Comment: What do you mean by $\max(S)$? I would suggest an induction argument on the index of $H$. If $|G:H| = 2$ then $H$ itself is maximal. Now suppose $|G:H| = n$, and the result is true for all proper subgroups with index smaller than $n$. If $H$ is not maximal then by definition there is some $K$ with $H < K < G$. Now $|G:K| < n$, so the induction hypothesis applies, and $K$ is contained in a maximal subgroup $M$, and therefore $H$ is also contained in $M$.

Comment: I am taking to be the largest subset of in $S$, but now I realize that won't work; there could be a subgroup between $H$ and $\max(S)$. So my argument does not work.

Comment: "The" largest subgroup in $S$ may not be unique (there may be multiple subsgroups in $S$ of the same maximal size). You can easily fix this by rephrasing as "choose a subgroup $M$ in $S$ with the largest possible size."

Comment: @Bungo So induction wouldn't be necessary, right?

Comment: P.S. There is no reason to consider subsets of $G$ which are not subgroups. You could instead define $S$ to be the set of all proper subgroups of $G$ which contain $H$, and choose a subgroup in $S$ of the largest possible size.

Comment: Induction seems like the cleanest way to make the argument formal. But for an informal argument, what I wrote in the "P.S." comment above would suffice. The problem is that for a finite group, the truth of the problem statement is more or less obvious, and any informal argument is likely to be just a rephrasing of the original statement.